# LPAD in oracle to return more then 6 character

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query

```
select lPAD('abcdef', 6, '0') from dual;
```

output is `abcdef`

```
select lPAD('abcdefij', 6, '0') from dual;
```

output is `abcdef` but it should be `abcedfij`

Comment: It is returning only 6 characters as expected. You must have done somthing wrong.

Comment: i am fresher ... need help plz

Comment: i want like `abcedfij`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LPAD` or `RPAD` means the maximum length of the output will be the value you specified. So the additional characters would be trimmed. The motto is like keep the length always with the value I give. Either add this character to it or trim the source

So, I think you need this.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(your_string) < 6 THEN
       lPAD(your_string, 6, '0')
       ELSE your_string
  END
FROM DUAL
```